# Beautifulsoup append html data

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, append

``Could someone tell me how to append all the datas in my var ?

```
name_company = soup.find_all("h1")
name_data = []
for item in name_company:
  name_data.append(item.string)
```

why when I print(name_data), there is only the last h1 who get scrap in my tuple ?

Thanks !

EDIT :

Here's my simplified code :

```
def robot_crawl(max_pages):
  page = 1
  while page < max_pages:
     url = "http://tel.local.ch/en/q/Vaud%20(Canton)/imprimerie.html?page=" + str(page)
     get_url = requests.get(url)
     get_text = get_url.text
     #take the text of the request
     soup = BeautifulSoup(get_text, "html.parser")
     for link in soup.find_all('a', {'class': "details-entry-title-link"}):
         href = link.get('href')
         bot_get_data(href)
     page += 1

def bot_get_data(item_url):
  source_code = requests.get(item_url)
  plain_text = source_code.text
  soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")
  name_company = soup.find_all("h1")

  name_data = []

  for item in name_company:
     name_data.append(item.string)
     print(item.string) #text or string ? don't know the diff



  excel_data_transfer(name_data)

def excel_data_transfer(dataname):
  workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('datasccraping3.xlsx')
  worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
  worksheet.write_column('A1', dataname)

  workbook.close()
```

Comment: All those 'h1' have strings? What is the value of len(name_company)?

Comment: yes they have and the len(name_company) is equal to 1

Comment: Strange. What does `print(soup.find_all("h1"))` prints?

Comment: It prints only the last company_name. I edited my question for you to have more informations. Really appreciate the help btw

Comment: @J.jaques I believe it should be `item.text` and an other thing, your func call `bot_get_data()` is above your func definition. Other than that, I don't see whats wrong here.

Comment: @Leuthus I tried it doesn't change anything ..

Comment: @J.jaques have your function `def bot_get_data(item_url):` somewhere above your `while` loop and put a break mark where your `find_all` is and follow your code and

Comment: Inspecting the html of of the robot_crawl function url I found only one `<h1>`. Maybe you want the `<h2>` tags?

Comment: In the page you mentioned there is only one `<h1>` tag.

Comment: I figured it out !! I used the module Global ! thx for your time =)